# Dynamic added tableRows not showing

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I got a `List` of `stings`, and i want to add as many `TableRows` as there are `strings` in the `list`. I got this working just fine in multiple other `activity's` in the same project. so i copied the code and it didn't work. The `TableRows` wasn't showing. So i commented out all unnecessary stuff and `debugged`, all code was run and no error. but the `TableRows` still not shows... is there something i have forgotten to import??

imports:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.R.color;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TableLayout.LayoutParams;
```

code:

```
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.MyTableLayout);

    for (int i =0; i< SomeList.size();i++){
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams p = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1.0f);
        tr.setLayoutParams(p);
        tr.setBackgroundColor(color.black);
        tl.addView(tr);
    }
```

XML:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/kategori_tl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Update:

So after some help in the comments I noticed that the main LinearLayout of the xml had height wrap_content so I changed it to match_parent instead. Now i get static TableRows if i add them in the xml but the dynamic am trying to add is still gone.

Comment: Go to developer options and enable show layoutbounds - that often helps - if not make a screenshot of it and post here

Comment: thanks for the hint. It don't show any of the TableRows am trying to add. 
i posted the xml but as i told i removed all unnecessary when debugging the problem. there are some views above the ScrollView thow

Comment: have you check if your `ScrollView` is actually in screen boundary?As you said there are other views in your layout. Make sure that  your `ScrollView` is not going out of the screen bounds.

Comment: Thanks. It seams like the ScrollView with all its content disapers.. I cheeked the layouts but they are all static heights and goes less than an cm from the top. I double checked with ligi's hint and they are all there none of them are stretching to the bottom of the screen. its just the main linear layout of the xml showing.